# how to contain a javascript class in asp.net form

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i need to use one of a java script class that i have in my template, and i can`t seem to understand what is going wrong there, my aspx file sayes this class is unknown for him
the name of the class is: show_hide, and it supposed to show/ hide the div below onclick on open/close icon.

my aspx file:

```
  <h2 class="title show_hide"><span class="close-icon"></span>some title</h2><div class="tabcontent-inner">
```

my master page:

```
<meta name="description" content="Page description" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" /><!-- grid stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" /><!-- layout stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/color-themes/blue.css" type="text/css" /><!-- color theme stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/textures/clean.css" type="text/css" /><!-- texture stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" /><!-- lightbox stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/markitup/skins/simple/style.css" type="text/css" /><!-- WYSWYG editor stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/markitup/sets/default/style.css" type="text/css" /><!-- WYSWYG editor stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" type="text/css" /><!-- jQuery UI stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
```

the class in js folder:

```
  // open/close boxes
  $('.show_hide span').click(function(elem){
    $(elem.target).toggleClass('open-icon');
    $(elem.target).parent().siblings('.module-box-inner').slideToggle();
  });
```

please help meeee im working on it for two days...

Comment: Where's your js files?

Comment: It should work. It is because you don't have this class in any css file but I think your browser will understand it and it will work perfectly

Comment: @Felix- my js files is inside of js folder and the class show_hide is inside a file named "common"..